# How to handle prerendered pages in Angular Universal with SSR and Express to avoid serving old cache after it's dropped?

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, pre-rendering

I have a company website running on Angular with SSR on. Unitl recently I was only using in-memory caching. But given the amount of pages we serve and deploys we make we decided to also prerender pages using angular prerendering feature: https://angular.io/guide/prerendering

After server starts we go through every page saved in `dist` folder and adding it to the in-memory cache. The problem is that after the content is changed and the cache is dropped, when new request is received by the server it still serves the prerendered page, instead of making a new one.

I was wondering if there was a way to drop the pre-rendered pages from express server once it was loaded to the local-cache and are no longer needed?

I tried deleting pre-rendered pages, but it results in a blank screen returned to FE.

I have also tried changing the options object sent to the render function, but it does not seem to work

Comment: Have you found any solution to it? Are you using any docker container to serve the application?